# alphabetically sorting binary search tree in c++

Tags: c++, sorting, file-io, binary-search-tree, alphabetical

I'm new to stackoverflow, i just got desperate and am hoping for a miracle.

I have to read in from a file a list of people with their info being
Last name (up to 20 characters)
First name (up to 20 characters)
House number (an integer)
Street (up to 20 characters)
City (up to 20 characters)
State abbreviation (up to 2 characters)
Zip (a 5 digit code)

I have to have two binary search trees, one sorted by zip code and one sorted by last name. The professor generally gives us a ton of info about the reasoning behind the code but absolutely nothing in terms of implementation. I'm pretty lost, especially when it comes to sorting strings alphabetically. I haven't even gotten to the part of the code where I read in from the file yet, but I'm trying to set up my methods first.

Any suggestions on how to create an alphabetically ordered c++ binary search tree? Do i need two different node structs and insert methods for it to be ordered by zip and last name?

here's my code so far

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iterator>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class inputInfo
{
    private:
    string tempLast;
    string tempFirst;
    int tempHouse;
    string tempStreet;
    string tempCity;
    string tempState;
    int tempZip;

    public:
    void setLast(string last);
    void setFirst(string first);
    void setHouse(int house);
    void setStreet(string street);
    void setCity(string city);
    void setState(string sate);
    void setZip(int zip);

    string getLast();
    string getFirst();
    int getHouse();
    string getStreet();
    string getCity();
    string getState();
    int getZip();
}
    void inputInfo::setLast(string last)
    {tempLast=last;}
    void inputInfo::setFirst(string first)
    {tempFirst=first;}
    void inputInfo::setHouse(int house)
    {tempHouse=house;}
    void inputInfo::setStreet(string street)
    {tempStreet=street;}
    void inputInfo::setCity(string city)
    {tempCity=city;}
    void inputInfo::setState(string state)
    {tempState=state;}
    void inputInfo::setZip(int zip)
    {tempZip=zip;}

    string inputInfo::getLast()
    {return tempLast;}
    string inputInfo::getFirst()
    {return tempFirst;}
    int inputInfo::getHouse()
    {return tempHouse;}
    string inputInfo::getStreet()
    {return tempStreet;}
    string inputInfo::getCity()
    {return tempCity;}
    string inputInfo::getState()
    {return tempState;}
    int inputInfo::getZip()
    {return tempZip;}

//Node structure for binary tree organized by zip   
struct zipNode{
    inputInfo data;
    zipNode* left;
    zipNode* right;
}   

//Function to creat a new node
zipNode* GetNewNode(inputInfo data){
    zipNode* newNode = new zipNode();
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->left=newNode->right=NULL;
    return newNode;
}
//insert data in BST, returns address of root node
zipNode* InsertZip(zipNode* root, inputInfo data){
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        root= GetNewNode(data);
    }

    else if(data.getZip() <= root->data.getZip())
    {
        root->left=Insert(root->left,data);
    }
    else
    {
        root->right=Insert(root->right,data);
    }
    return root;
}

struct nameNode{
    inputInfo data;
    nameNode* left;
    nameNode* right;
}   

//Function to creat a new node
nameNode* GetNewNode(inputInfo data){
    nameNode* newNode = new nameNode();
    nameNode->data = data;
    nameNode->left=newNode->right=NULL;
    return newNode;
}
//insert data in BST, returns address of root node
nameNode* InsertName(nameNode* root, inputInfo data){
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        root= GetNewNode(data);
    }

    else if(data.getLast() <= root->data.getLast())
    {
        root->left=Insert(root->left,data);
    }
    else
    {
        root->right=Insert(root->right,data);
    }
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Aside: `class inputInfo` really doesn't do anything but clutter up your code. IMHO a `struct Person { string last_name, string first_name, int house_number, string street, string city, string state, int zip }` is a far clearer abstraction to store your data.

Comment: If you have inserted data correctly in BST, traverse it in In-Order Traversal to get sorted result. Check this reference for string comparson http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lexicographical_compare/

Comment: So in order to sort alphabetically I'm going to need to store my last names as an array of characters instead of strings right Abdul?

Comment: @Briana Not necessarily, you can apply this method on strings too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any Binary Search Tree when traversed in Inorder results in a sorted array.

If you want to sort strings just compare it normally like you do with integers as c++ has all those functions in built.

And after you have successfully inserted the data. Apply Inorder traversal and you will get an alphabetically sorted array.
Just include
and then you can compare strings like normal data type[for eg. str1 > str2 ]